# UI test with teststack framework jenkins integration

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, mstest, vstest

On my project we have some ui test made with **teststack white in VS2012**.
These tests need to control the mouse. I have a bat file that if i run it manually the tests run with **mstest or vstest.console** but when i run them from **jenkins** it says that **local.runsettings** is not found (if executed with vstestconsole, but the file is located in the same folder with the bat file) and if run with mstest the app and mstest process are started (if i look in task manager) but nothing happends on the screen. I have also tried the mstest plugin and vstest plugin in jenkins and it has the same effect.

What is the problem? What should i do ?

Comment: You need to add some code

Answer (score 0):

The main Jenkins executor is headless, so you have to add **slave** for UI testing. It could run on the same machine.

Cheers

Comment: I have another computer as a slave. What do you mean by headless?

Comment: I mean that Jenkins process running as a background process on a master, so you can't perform keyboard and mouse actions.